# Issues with multiple R Shiny modals not displaying

Tags: r, shiny

I asked a question regarding this issue here before and it seems as though it's been deleted?  Because I know I got a solution from a comment here...never would have figured it out on my own...but I can no longer find the post.

Regardless, here's the basic situation.  I have an app that takes a large amount of data from a database, puts it in a somewhat customizable `DT` table, and then allows the user to filter and download.  I'm trying to add functionality where the user can select one or more rows that they think are incorrect and provide comments on them.

My previous post dealt with this issue.  I was trying to loop through all the selected rows and display a modal pop-up each time to gather their inputs to push back to the database, and the app was only showing the last modal.  Someone here gave me a solution where the `currentModalIndex` was manually manipulated.  As I said, I never would have figured that out, and though I thought I understood what was happening there, it appears I really don't.

Here's a (fairly) minimal example that shows the working multi-modals with the solution that I got from the now missing post.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(magrittr)

ids <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
firstNames <- c("Bob", "Jane", "Jim", "Billy", "Siouxsie")
lastNames <- c("Smith", "Jones", "Thomas", "Idol", "Sioux")
FaveColors <- c("Blue", "Green", "Yellow", "Red", "Black")
gender <- c("Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female")
df <- data.frame(ids, firstNames, lastNames, FaveColors, gender)


# Define UI 
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Minimal Example"),
  
  # Sidebar 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      tabPanel("Columns",
               checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "ColumnsToShow", label = "Output Columns",
                                  choices = names(df)
               )
      ),
      selectInput(inputId = "gender",
                  label = "Gender", 
                  choices = c("Male", "Female")
      ),
      
      actionButton(inputId = "ErrorButton", label="Comment on selected rows")
    ),
    
    # Show a table
    mainPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput("FilteredDataFrame")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic 
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  currentModalIndex <- reactiveVal(0)
  
  observeEvent(input$ErrorButton, {
    currentModalIndex(1) # reset index to 1
  })
  
  observeEvent(currentModalIndex(), {
    
    my_df <- filtered_df()
    
    
    if (currentModalIndex() > 0 && currentModalIndex() <= length(input$FilteredDataFrame_rows_selected)) {
      fname <- my_df[input$FilteredDataFrame_rows_selected[currentModalIndex()],"firstNames"]
      lname <- my_df[input$FilteredDataFrame_rows_selected[currentModalIndex()],"lastNames"]
      myString <- paste("You have selected the row for ", fname, lname)
      showModal(modalDialog(
        title = "Report possible data error",
        myString,
        footer = actionButton("nextModal", "Next"),
        easyClose = FALSE,
        fade = TRUE
      ))
    }
  })
  
 
  observeEvent(input$nextModal, {
    if (currentModalIndex() < length(input$FilteredDataFrame_rows_selected)) {
      currentModalIndex(currentModalIndex() + 1)
    } else {
      currentModalIndex(0) # reset index to 0, indicating no more modals to show
      removeModal()
    }
  })
  
  filtered_df <- reactive({
    temp_frame <- df %>% filter(gender == input$gender) %>% select(all_of(input$ColumnsToShow))
    return(temp_frame)
  })
  
  output$FilteredDataFrame <- DT::renderDT(server=TRUE, {datatable(filtered_df(), extensions = 'Buttons',
                                                                   options = list(scrollx=TRUE,
                                                                                  lengthMenu = c(10,20,30),
                                                                                  paging = TRUE,
                                                                                  searching = TRUE,
                                                                                  fixedColumns = TRUE,
                                                                                  autoWidth = TRUE,
                                                                                  ordering = TRUE,
                                                                                  #dom = 'Bfrtip',
                                                                                  dom = 'tlip',
                                                                                  buttons = c('copy', 
                                                                                              'csv',
                                                                                              'excel')
                                                                   )
  )
  }
  )
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

You can run that, select multiple rows, and hit the `Comment on Selected Rows` button and it will loop through and correctly display the names from the selected rows.  In the actual app the modal will have input fields to gather data and push an SQL update query back to the database.

The issue that I'm having is that I need to gather some identifying information about the person making the update.  In practice this will be several fields but for now let's just get their name.  I want this modal to show up once, the first time they click to comment on selections.  After that there is no need for it to show up again as I have already captured the info.  I thought that I could check to see if a name variable still had the default value and if it did, pop up the get name modal and be off...but the modal never shows up, even though I can `cat` output to the console showing that I was in the code to call it.  Clearly this still requires manipulation of that `currentModalIndex` but I'm not sure how to proceed.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(magrittr)

ids <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
firstNames <- c("Bob", "Jane", "Jim", "Billy", "Siouxsie")
lastNames <- c("Smith", "Jones", "Thomas", "Idol", "Sioux")
FaveColors <- c("Blue", "Green", "Yellow", "Red", "Black")
gender <- c("Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female")
df <- data.frame(ids, firstNames, lastNames, FaveColors, gender)

contactName = "Name"

########################################################## Modal form for contact info

contactModal <- function(failed = FALSE, Problematic = "") {
  modalDialog(
    textInput("InputName", contactName),

    if (failed)
      div(tags$b(paste("There was an issue with your input for", Problematic), style = "color: red;")),
    
    footer = tagList(
      modalButton("Cancel"),
      actionButton("ok", "OK")
    )
  )
}



# Define UI 
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Minimal Example"),

    # Sidebar 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            tabPanel("Columns",
                      checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "ColumnsToShow", label = "Output Columns",
                                         choices = names(df)
                      )
            ),
            selectInput(inputId = "gender",
                        label = "Gender", 
                        choices = c("Male", "Female")
            ),
                        
            actionButton(inputId = "ErrorButton", label="Comment on selected rows")
        ),

        # Show a table
        mainPanel(
          DT::dataTableOutput("FilteredDataFrame")
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic 
server <- function(input, output) {

  currentModalIndex <- reactiveVal(0)
  vals <- reactiveValues(txt = NULL)
  
  observeEvent(input$ErrorButton, {
    currentModalIndex(1) # reset index to 1
  })
  
  observeEvent(currentModalIndex(), {
    if (currentModalIndex() > 0 && currentModalIndex() <= length(input$FilteredDataFrame_rows_selected)) {
      #myString <- paste("You have selected row", input$FilteredDataFrame_rows_selected[currentModalIndex()])
      fname <- df[input$FilteredDataFrame_rows_selected[currentModalIndex()],"firstNames"]
      lname <- df[input$FilteredDataFrame_rows_selected[currentModalIndex()],"lastNames"]
      myString <- paste("You have selected the row for ", fname, lname)
      showModal(modalDialog(
        title = "Report possible data error",
        myString,
        footer = actionButton("nextModal", "Next"),
        easyClose = FALSE,
        fade = TRUE
      ))
    }
  })
  
  ############################################ok button for contact info modal
  observeEvent(input$ok, {
    
    errorState = FALSE
    
    #Check for name
    if (!errorState){
      if (!is.null(input$InputName) && nzchar(input$InputName)) {
        vals$Name <- input$InputName
        contactName <<- input$InputName            # note the <<- for the global variable
        removeModal()
      } else {
        errorState <- TRUE
        showModal(contactModal(failed = TRUE, Problematic = "name"))
      }
    }
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$nextModal, {
    if (currentModalIndex() < length(input$FilteredDataFrame_rows_selected)) {
      currentModalIndex(currentModalIndex() + 1)
    } else {
      currentModalIndex(0) # reset index to 0, indicating no more modals to show
      removeModal()
    }
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$ErrorButton, {
    
    #get contact info if we don't already have it
    if (contactName == "Name")  {
      
       cat(file=stderr(), "About to pop the show contact modal \n")
       showModal(contactModal())
     }
    
    currentModalIndex(1) # reset index to 1
        
  })
      
  

  filtered_df <- reactive({
    temp_frame <- df %>% filter(gender == input$gender) %>% select(all_of(input$ColumnsToShow))
    return(temp_frame)
  })

  output$FilteredDataFrame <- DT::renderDT(server=TRUE, {datatable(filtered_df(), extensions = 'Buttons',
                                                                   options = list(scrollx=TRUE,
                                                                                  lengthMenu = c(10,20,30),
                                                                                  paging = TRUE,
                                                                                  searching = TRUE,
                                                                                  fixedColumns = TRUE,
                                                                                  autoWidth = TRUE,
                                                                                  ordering = TRUE,
                                                                                  #dom = 'Bfrtip',
                                                                                  dom = 'tlip',
                                                                                  buttons = c('copy', 
                                                                                              'csv',
                                                                                              'excel')
                                                                   )
  )
  }
  )
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Any guidance would be most appreciated.

Comment: I recently left a related answer [here](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/3835#issuecomment-1778736835).